# Problem with updating PrimeNg table using BehaviourSubject and filtering

Tags: angular, rxjs, primeng

I'm using p-table in template

```
<p-table #dt [value]="customers" (onFilter)="changeValue($event)">
```

where customers are provided by subscription in component

```
this.subscription = this.customerDataService.getCustomerSubject().subscribe(data => {
  if (data) {
    this.customers = data;
  }
},  (error) => this.handleError(error));
```

service fragment:

```
        export class CustomerDataService {
        
          customerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Customer[]>([]);
        
          getCustomerSubject() {
            return this.customerSubject.asObservable();
          }
        
          getAllCustomers() {
            return this.customerSubject.getValue();
          }
      setCustomers(customers: Customer[]) {
        this.customerSubject.next(customers);
      }
        
          constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
          }
        
          getCustomers() {
            const url = decorateUrl(UrlConstants.URL_CUSTOMER);
            this.httpClient.get<Customer[]>(url).subscribe(customers => this.customerSubject.next(customers),
              (error)=> this.customerSubject.error(error)
            )
        
          }
          
            removeCustomer(customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {
            const url = decorateUrl(UrlConstants.URL_CUSTOMER_REMOVE);
            return this.httpClient.put<any>(url, customer, httpOptions)
              .pipe(
                catchError(handleError),
                map(value => value),
                tap({next: () => this.removeItem(customer)})
              );
          }
          
            removeItem(item: Customer) {
            let currentItems = this.getAllCustomers();
            let currentIndex = currentItems.findIndex(el => el.id === item.id);
            if (currentIndex > 0) {
              currentItems.splice(currentIndex, 1);
            }
            this.customerSubject.next(currentItems);
          }
         }
```

In customerDataService I update table for CRUD operations after getting response from back, send next to subscription. All CRUD operations work fine without using filters.
When I use filters I need to change [value] for correct behavoiur on ui when I remove/add the row, for that I listen onFilter event and pass to [value] filteredValues via next.
in component:

```
  changeValue(event: any) {
    this.customerDataService.setCustomers(event.filteredValue);
  }
```

But it doesn't work in case I remove symbols in filter - property [value] always has filteredValues which was sent to subscription. Could anyone advice me how can I manage it?
problem: filter stop working on deleting symbols after changing [value] to filteredValue(ex. here I remove 'r' and filter is not applied)
[image]

Comment: Please provide more code, working stackblitz with the issue and screenshots of what's wrong!

Comment: What `Primeng` version do you using? Acutally, I'm also face this issue before specially with table that coming with sort or filter feature on Primeng V.10; The happen is, when table get sorted or filtered, table will generate the fake list and display that one instead of the original one. So after you update your data_list make sure you set `clear` to the table and bring all filter and sorting back programmatically by yourself.

Comment: I use v13, filtering and updating table via BehaviourSubject are ok when I add symbols in filter input. But when I remove symbols bug appears, because values in template contains only filteredvalues(not all from backside)

Answer (score 0):

Probably my fix helps someone:

1. I created table variable in component

```
@ViewChild("dt", { static: false }) public dt: Table | undefined;
```

2. in subscription I check if filters exists and if yes - call them

```
    if (this.dt && Object.keys(this.dt?.filters!).length) {
      Object.entries(this.dt?.filters!).map(([key, val]) => {
        let {value, matchMode} = <FilterMetadata>val;
        this.dt?.filter(value, key, matchMode ?? '');
      })
    }
```

If someone provides another solution - it will be great